# listing elements from bottom to top (but not in reverse order)

Tags: html, angularjs, css, css-position

#### Situation

I have a design where `categories` are displayed on a square `product`.
There can be one `category` or up to 3 `categories`.

#### Problem

The design requires the categories to be listed from the bottom to the top. The categories are displayed as `<div>category-1</div>` text. Each category has a height of `80px` and a custom width (max 200px).

Is it possible to do this with CSS only and for at least IE9?

I can use angular JS if a CSS-only solution is not possible.

---

At the moment it looks like this when there are 2 categories.

[image]

I need to make it look like this:

[image]

I could add a margin-top in that case, but as soon as there is only 1 category it looks like this:
[image]

It should always be the same space between FOOTER and the last category.

**EDIT**:

Not sure if it's important but there is a maximum of 3 categories and a minimum of 1 category.

Looks like I wasn't clear enough so I made an example on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/k3ve49uj/

The last result is what I need. Even if there is only 1 category, it should stick to the bottom. I used a `<br/>` to simulate that.

Unfortunately I can't show the actual HTML & CSS because it's work for a client. But I'll be able to apply the changes later on.

#### Info

Please don't work on the code I provided, it's just to demonstrate what I need. Basically there is a container & all elements inside it have to be positioned from THE BOTTOM to the TOP. Not the other way around.

#### Snippet

```css
.pr.product {
 width: 380px;
 height: 380px;
 background-image: url("http://unsplash.it/380/380?random&blur");
 margin: 30px;
 position: relative;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.product .headline {
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
 bottom: 60px;
 width: 75%;
}

.product .category_wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 right: 20px;
 width: 20%;
 bottom: 140px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
 height: 60px;
 top: 255px;
}
.product footer {
 text-align: right;
 color: red;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;
 right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>
  Looks good, but only if 3 categories are available.
  </h3>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="headline">
      <h1>Test headline</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="category_wrapper">
      <div class="category">category-1</div>
      <div class="category">category-2</div>
      <div class="category">category-3</div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>

  <hr/>
  <h3>
    Only 2 categories (they stick to the top)
    </h3>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="headline">
      <h1>Test headline</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="category_wrapper">
      <div class="category">category-1</div>
      <div class="category">category-2</div>

    </div>
    <footer>
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>

  <hr/>
  <h3>
      Desired output if only 2 tags
    </h3>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="headline">
      <h1>Test headline</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="category_wrapper">
      <br/>
      <div class="category">category-1</div>
      <div class="category">category-2</div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you want. But I'm not sure it will go with the CSS you are using without watching it. Try this or provide your CSS for the list and footer if it does not work this way.

```css
#footer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: red;
}

ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Category 1</li>
  <li>Category 2</li>
</ul>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

**UPDATE**

**[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3ve49uj/1/)** using your updated code and let me know.

Just need to update your `.product .category_wrapper` as below

```
.product .category_wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;
            width: 20%;
            bottom: 60px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
            height: auto;
        }
```

Comment: @praszyk please add the HTML too

Comment: yea, that did the trick. Not sure why I didn't see that. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your CSS like this, it will do what you ask.

```
.product .category_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    width: 20%;
    bottom: 70px;
    height: auto;
}
.product .category_wrapper .category {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of elements can vary from 1-4 then the height of the list is effectively variable - try removing the `height` and  `top` values from `category_wrapper` in your stylesheet.

Comment: The space between footer and last category has to be the same all the time. If I remove the height & top properties from category_wrapper, they stick to the top. The elements inside category_wrapper should be positioned from bottom to top.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping they would continue to stick to the bottom because of the bottom property being set! I wonder could you use float... That works relative to the parent doesn't it (not 100%sure)? If you set position to relative instead of absolute that is.